# Pinch zoom not working in Iframe inside ion-scroll

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using below code

```
<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width: 100%;height:100%" delegate-handle="zoom-pane" class="zoom-pane" min-zoom="1" scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-y="false" overflow-scroll="false">
        <iframe id="rframe" 
            ng-src="{{rm._iframe}}" 
            style="height: 100%;width: 100%;",
            name="r_container">
        </iframe>
    </ion-scroll>
```

But on rendering I am not able to zoom in content of iframe. What's the issue here

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same problem.